# The Cantor Space as $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and as $[0,1]$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, logic, fractals

The Cantor-Space is defined as the space of all infinite binary sequences, i.e. the space $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. It has a natural metric,
$$
  d(x,y) = \inf\{ 2^{-|w|} : w \in pref(x) \cap pref(y) \}
$$
where $pref(x)$ denotes the set of all prefixes of $x$ (i.e. finite initial segments of an infinite binary sequence/string).

Let $X = \{0,1\}$ and $X^*$ denote all finite sequences over $X$. Then the open, closed and clopen sets are characterised as follows:

1) Open sets are of the form $W \cdot X^{\mathbb{N}}$, where $W \subseteq X^*$.

2) A subset $E \subseteq X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is open and closed (clopen) iff $E = W \cdot X^{\mathbb{N}}$ where $W \subset X^*$ is finite.

3) A subset $F \subseteq X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is closed iff $F = \{ \xi : pref(\xi) \subseteq pref(F) \}$.

Now every $x = x_1 x_2 x_3 \ldots \in X^{\mathbb{N}}$ could be identified with an element from $[0,1]$ by the dyadic interpretation
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} x_i
$$
and by identifiying sequences of the form $010000...$ and $001111...$ one gets an isomorphism. Now I ask myself how look the images of closed, open and clopen sets under this isomorphism, if $x$ is closed, then the image is also a closed subset of $[0,1]$, but what about the open sets?

EDIT: Corrected definition of $d(x,y)$.

EDIT: Corrected last equation.

EDIT: To clarify point 3).

**Lemma:** Let $L$ be a subset of $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ and let $u \in X^{\mathbb{N}}$. Then $u \in \overline{L}$ iff every prefix of $u$ is a prefix of a word of $L$.

**Proof**: We have $u \in \overline{X}$ iff for each $n \ge 0$ there exists $v \in L$ such that $d(u,v) < 2^{-n}$. This amounts to saying that, for each $n \ge 0, u_1\ldots u_n$ is a prefix of a word of $L$. q.e.d.

Note that $d(x,y)$ could also be written:
$$
 d(x,y) = 2^{-r} \quad where \quad r = \operatorname{min}\{ n | x_n \ne y_n \}.
$$

Comment: Your definition of the metric $d(x, y)$ doesn't quite make sense as written.  What is $w$?  Also, what is the condition being asserted about $pref(x) \cap pref(y)$?

Comment: Your last equation does not make sense.

Comment: I think you want your metric to be $d(x,y)= 2^{-w}$ where $w$ is the position of the first disagreement between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the closed sets.  You have to derive them from the definition of open sets.  Let me choose the open set consisting of all strings that start with $00$ or with $11$.  The complement, which is closed, is all strings starting with $10$ or $01$ but I am not sure how to read the definition in 3) to get this.  It seems like a string starting with $00$ starts with $0$ and this is a prefix of something in $F$.

Comment: the sets of all strings starting with $00$ or with $11$ and the set of all strings starting with $10$ or $01$ are both open and closed. for your example the string $0$ is obvisouly a prefix of a string starting with $00$. I added to my post an edit to clarify point 3).

Comment: I'm not that clear on what you want to know. Your map is a homeomorphism, so it preserves all closed, open, and clopen sets.

Comment: yes, for example the image under this map of all strings with prefix $0$ is the set $[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}]$, which is closed, and so is the set of all strings $0 \cdot X^{\mathbb{N}}$. But what confused me is that the set $0 \cdot X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is also open, but its image $[0.25, 0.5]$ is not??

Comment: You're saying the map is a homeomorphism, right? So, the image of an open set should be open.

Comment: Could you re-state the precise question? I am not sure what to say.

Comment: Yes, what exactly is the question?  You are considering three spaces: (1) the Cantor space $C$, (2) a quotient $\overline{C}$ of $C$, obtained by identifying certain pairs, (3) the unit interval $[0,1]$.  The quotient map $C\to\overline{C}$ does not map open sets to open sets, but the homeomorphism $\overline{C} \to [0,1]$ does.

Comment: the map replacing $2$ by $1$ in the ternary representation of a number in $[0,1]$ is not a homeomorphism?