# The connected component of space $X=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

$X=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ of sequences $x=(x_j)_{i=1}^\infty $ of zeros and ones.

$d(x,y)=2^{-n}$ if $x_i=y_i$ for $1\le i\le n$, $x_n\neq y_n$ and let $d(x,x)=0$

What are the connected components of $(X,d)$?

I guess the connected components of $X$ are the one point sets which are connected.

Suppose the connected component $S$ is the set containing at least two points. I want to use the definition of disconnectedness to get a contradiction, but I have no idea how to get two open sets $U, V$ with $U\cap V=\emptyset $ in $S$ such that $U\cup V=S$.

Also, I am trying to prove $X\times X$ with the product topology is homeomorphic to $X$.

I think the map $f:X \rightarrow X\times X$ defined by$(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)\rightarrow ((x_1,x_3,...),(x_2,x_4,...))$ is a bijection, but how should I prove it is continuous.

Comment: This question may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357121/the-cantor-space-as-0-1-mathbbn-and-as-0-1?rq=1

Comment: Note that the distance $d$ induces the Tychonoff topology. Find an appropriate basis and both questions will be solved easily. Hint: consider the sequences with the first $k$ elements fixed.

Comment: Hint: if  $x \ne  x'$, there is some $i$ for which $x_i \ne x'_i$. Split $S$ into one subset with $s_i = 0$ and one with $s_i = 1$.

Comment: Do you know that a continuous image of a connected set is connected? And do you know that the projection map $$(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)\mapsto x_n$$ is continuous?